# "Error found when loading /etc/profile" on login after upgrade

Tags: bash, 18.04

I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. After upgrading, on the login I get the message

```
Error found  when loading /etc/profile.
```

The error is in `/usr/share/modules/init/sh` file on line 43 and line 61. However I couldn't figure out why it is generated. The error reads:

```
/usr/share/modules/init/sh:eval:line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `(' 
/usr/share/modules/init/sh:eval:line 43: ` untitled(1) _mlshddbg=" ;;'
/usr/share/modules/init/sh:eval:line 61: export: module: not a function
```

The lines in `/usr/share/modules/init/sh` that causes errors are 
(line no. 39 to 43):

```
if [ -n "${_mlIFS+x}" ]; then   
   IFS=$_mlIFS; unset _mlIFS;
else
   unset IFS;
fi;
```

And line 61 is:

```
export -f module
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Run `shellcheck` on the whole script. You may have to `sudo apt install shellcheck` first

Comment: **Vote to close** Problem has been solved without details being posted.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The correct way to deal with this situation is to post the solution as an answer, as Samurai did, not close it.

Comment: @Tim When I VTC'd there was no answer. The VTC helped prompt OP to post an answer 10 hours later. However the answer doesn't show the lines in error nor the `shellcheck` syntax changes recommendations. As such the answer "shellcheck fixed the syntax" is of same quality as old comment of "shellcheck did the trick".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don’t think the quality of the answers is a reason to vote to close a question...

Comment: @Tim That is normally true, but this is a self-answered question which I think comes with higher quality expectations. In this case it could be a learning tool about `shellcheck` abilities for example. I myself was thinking of a self-answered question on `shellcheck`'s inability to read `source` files. Then creating a script that merged source file + main script into `/tmp` directory and running `shellcheck` on combined file. In any respect, OP can improve answer and question could be reopened I think. This is a democracy and not a dictatorship so my vote holds no more weight than anyone elses

Answer (score 1):

Running `shellcheck` on `/usr/share/modules/init/sh` file gave following recommendations on the multiple lines leading upto the line 43.   :

1. `` if [ -n "`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'+x}'`" ]; then ``

   ```
            ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
                          ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
   ```
2. `` module() { eval `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modulecmd-compat sh $*`; } ``

   ```
                    ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
                    ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
                                                                    ^-- SC2048: Use "$@" (with quotes) to prevent whitespace problems.
                                                                    ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
   ```

The above recommendation  can be incorporated in the following manner :

1. `if [ -n "$(eval 'echo ${"$_mlv"+x}')" ]; then`
2. `module() {  eval "$(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modulecmd-compat sh "$*")"; }`